# adding user controls programatically to an updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, dynamic-usercontrols

In my asp.net application, I need to be able to dynamically add user controls based on data in a database.

For example, on `page1`, I will bind three elements to a repeater:

1. some html content
2. a user control
3. more html content.

The repeater on the page is surrounded by an updatepanel

```
(updatemode=conditional, childrenastriggers=false)
```

The user control also has it's own updatepanet

```
(updatemode=conditional, childrenastriggers=true)
```

So, what I have is something like this:

```
outer update panel<br/>
  repeater<br/>
    item 1 = html<br/>
    item 2 = user control<br/>
      user control update panel<br/>
        user control content<br/>
      /user control update panel<br/>
     item 3 = html<br/>
  /repeater<br/>
/outer update panel<br/>
```

The problem is, I don't get any events fired by my user control.  I'm pretty sure I need to create the control in the page_init, but I'm a little unsure of how to do this, since I may have to create any number of user controls of different types, and place them at different locations on the page.  Has anyone ever run into this problem before, and how did you solve it?

Comment: Maybe this might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/163038/Approaches-for-User-Control-Event-Handling

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. Add add a placeholder control to updatepanel.
2. In CS file create a instance of your usercontrol.
3. Add that control to placeholder.